# Use disk-backed buffer between pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, buffer

I'd like to pipe a command into a slower one, with a rather big (~200GB) buffer in between. Here is an example use-case:

```
command1 | buffer -f file.buffer | command2
```

Is there a command to do that? The ones I saw only buffered to memory.

Now that I think about it, would this achieve the desired result?

```
#!/bin/bash
# buffer.sh
FILE="$1"
tail -F "$FILE" 2> /dev/null &
cat > "$FILE"
```

Though I'm not sure how to stop the tail once it has read everything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found [`mbuffer`](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html).

Apparently the option `-t` uses a temporary file for huge buffer, which is exactly what I was looking for. Alternatively with `-T /path/to/file` I can choose which of my mounted filesystems will hold the file.

I also note the file gets deleted just after it's opened, so `ls` doesn't show it. Still `ls -l /proc/<PID of mbuffer>/fd` confirms it's there.

So my example becomes:

```
command1 | mbuffer -T file.buffer -m 200G | command2
```